# Why does futurebuilder keep fetching data everytime TextFormField is pressed?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a statelsess widget built like this where a futurebuilder fetches data and then returns a StatefullTextFormFieldWidget:

```
Statless Widget{

     build:
     Futurebuilder(snapshot, context){
     future: GetDocumentFromFirebase(id);

      if(snapshot.hasData){

          return StatefullTextFormFieldWidget(snapshot);

      }
    
    }
```

}

The StatefullTextFormfieldWidget contains a appbar and scaffold with with 2 TextFormFields and workes as it should (when it was offline).

The bug occurs when  any of my forms gets onFocusScope in the StatefullTextFormFieldWidget. Then the future starts to refetch data from firebase. It does NOT trigger the rebuild function so my app actually works fine since the state remains, but the main problem is that the app unnecessarily starts fetching data from firestore everytime the user clicks on a TextFormField. I only want to fetch data once when the user enter the screen and then stick with that snapshot as long as the user remains on the screen.

I really cant understand how the futurebuilder can continue fetch data without being rebuilt.

FuturebuilderWidget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:MyApp/manage_orders/handle/widgets/form_has_handling.dart';
import 'package:MyApp/services/firestore.dart';
import 'package:MyApp/services/models.dart';

class HandleOrderScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/handle-order-screen';

  @override
  State<HandleOrderScreen> createState() => _HandleOrderScreenState();
}

class _HandleOrderScreenState extends State<HandleOrderScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final String id = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;

    return FutureBuilder<Map>(
        future: FirestoreService().getOrderPriceUserBoat(id),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text(''),
              ),
              body: Center(
                child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
              ),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('Error'),
              ),
              body: Center(
                child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
              ),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            var snapshotData = snapshot.data;
            Order order = snapshotData!['order'];

            return TextFormFieldWidget(order: order);
          } else {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('Error'),
              ),
              body: Center(
                child: Text('Something went wrong'),
              ),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

TextFormFieldWidget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:MyApp/services/models.dart';

class TextFormFieldWidgetextends StatefulWidget {
  const TextFormFieldWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.order,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Order order;

  @override
  State<FormHasHandlingWidget> createState() => _TextFormFieldWidgetState();
}

class _TextFormFieldWidgetState extends State<TextFormFieldWidget> {
  final commentController = TextEditingController();
  final priceController = TextEditingController();
  static final formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Handle'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              height: size.height - 120,
              child: Form(
                key: formkey,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: 120,
                      child: Card(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 241, 235, 235),
                        child: Container(
                          child: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                              children: <TextSpan>[
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: 'Test Name\n',
                                ),
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: 'Order.nr:',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: '${widget.order.orderNumber} \n',
                                ),
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: 'Car: ',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: widget.order.carModel + '\n',
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: Text(
                          " Type:",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: priceController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Price: '),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value != null) {
                              if (value.length < 1) {
                                return 'Wright the price';
                              } else {
                                return null;
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: commentController,
                          decoration:
                              InputDecoration(labelText: 'Description:'),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                          minLines: 2,
                          maxLines: 5,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value != null) {
                              if (value.length < 10) {
                                return 'Give a short description';
                              } else {
                                return null;
                              }
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        child: Text('Send in'),
                        onPressed: () {},
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            fixedSize: Size(size.width, 50),
                            primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 223, 208, 0)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        child: Text('Finish order'),
                        onPressed: () {},
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            fixedSize: Size(size.width, 50),
                            primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 17, 0)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 200,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: could you include both classes in full code?

Comment: I included both classes now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your `GetDocumentFromFirebase` function does a new `get()` call to Firestore each time it runs, which happens every time the widget is rendered.

If you want to prevent refetching the document every time, put the code in a stateful widget, and keep the `Future<DocumentSnapshot>` in a state variable that you only initialize once.

Also see Randal's excellent explanation on [Fixing a common FutureBuilder and StreamBuilder problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg)

Comment: I also found what you are saying when i searched for information and I tried to put the document read inside the initstate but the same error still occured. I think it since the error occurs even thought the Futurebuilder never gets rebuilt it doesent matter if the document read is placed inside the initstate.  Since its only built once, which ive checked 100% with printmessages everytime it gets bult.  Or do I missunderstand what youre saying? I gonna check out the video and se if it can help me.

Comment: Was just about to link to my video myself. :)  Thanks for the link.

Comment: Hi Randal I checked out your video and placed the future in the stateconstructor but I still got the same error. I dont think its the exact case like your video showed since my parentwidget with the futurebuilder never gets rebuilt. I can see that my firestore call gets reruned everytime my child-form-widget change state and rebuilds  but my parrent widget where futurebuilder is never rebuilds which makes it a very strange error. @RandalSchwartz

Comment: I found the solution. It was as the video stated but with a twist! It turns out that it wasnt the parent class that I attached which was triggered, but the grandfaderclass (parrents-parrent-class :p). When the Textformfield was pressed it didnt rebuild the futurebuilder that initiated the TextFormFieldWidget but it rebuilt the futurebuilder that Navigated to this futurebuilder. Hence I thought it was this futurebuilder that called firestore again without being rebuilt. But why it did skip one step and triggered the futurebuilder one genereation ahead is still a mistery to me.

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out and got it working @cueless 